# Sublime doesn't auto-reload tree and files when changing brach - working via WSL

Tags: git, sublimetext3, wsl-2

I started using WSL2 with Ubuntu distribution for Ruby on Rails development. I have Sublime 3 installed on Windows and I'm accesing the projects in Sublime via network location `\\wsl$\<distro>` . When I change branch via git in the terminal though and go back to Sublime it doesn't automatically reload the files and folders tree. I can do it manually by `Project > Refresh Folders` and by pressing `F5` for every opened file but its rather annoying.

Is this caused by the fact that Sublime runs in Windows while the files are in WSL distro (even though they're accessible from Windows)? Is there a way to make the auto reload work in this configuration? (I know there's Auto Refresh plugin for Sublime, but you have to give it file names manually and and it works in intervals).

Comment: Are you just using WSL through the command line, or do you have a graphical interface installed as well? If you do, you might want to try installing Sublime for Linux. That way it can be aware of file system events through the OS.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I have installed graphical interface using this manual: https://medium.com/@japheth.yates/the-complete-wsl2-gui-setup-2582828f4577 and using Sublime from Linux works like a charm :)